# SVG convert <g> tag to an <image> tag containing base64 PNG URI (read more)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I got an interesting problem (I hope!)
I have noticed that there are two "types" of SVGs

First we have the conventional SVG file with  and  tags for example:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 841.89 1190.55" style="enable-background:new 0 0 841.89 1190.55;" xml:space="preserve">
     <g id="Background">
        <rect id="Color1" class="st3" width="840.94" height="1190.55"/>
        <g id="Texture" class="st4">
            <path class="st5" d="M843.67,410.13c-73.29 ...
```

Secondly we have embedded  tags in the image, not sure what to call them, so I've just named them "fake SVG", an example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="3718" height="4899" viewBox="0 0 3718 4899">
  <image id="Lager_1" data-name="Lager 1" width="185.9" height="244.95000000000002" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh ...
```

My question is: **Is there is any smooth way to convert a conventional SVG into a "fake" SVG?** (please tell me if they have a real name). Also keep in mind that I would like to keep the groupings so each `<g>` should convert to a `<image>` tag

**My thoughts:** I am thinking about loading the conventional SVG into a `<canvas>` tag, it seems to be able to understand the `<g>` groupings in the conventional SVG well and consistently, and from there, somehow, convert those groups individually into base64 PNG URI, and reconstruct it into a fake SVG, perhaps there should be some library out there that can help out, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why would you do that? Embedding raster images is needed to ... well ... embed **raster** images. Rasterizing your svg will definitely reduce the quality of your current vector drawings, and possibly increase its size (in bytes), i.e loose-loose strategy. If you wish to embed your current vector image as a vector image stored in a data URL loaded by the `<image>`, then you'd keep the quality, but waste a lot of disk-space for nothing, and make the decoder do a lot more work since it will have to maintain more images contexts...

Comment: Yes I have considered that, please correct me if I am wrong. I did some experimentation and it seems like a large vectorised svg is faster to serve to the client, but takes a long time for the client to load. While a raster "fake" svg takes longer time to serve but is faster to load. That being said, in my experimentation, it seems like serving raster "fake" svg offer a better user experience. I used a 7MB vectorised svg file in my experimentation.

Comment: I also want to allow the user to edit the image, I concluded that moving a group by mouse drag in a `<canvas>`is significantly slower when dealing with a vectorized SVG, as compared to a raster "fake" SVG.

Comment: Yes it will be faster to render a raster image on a canvas than a vector one, but why would you wrap it in a svg? Just serve the raster directly in that case.

Comment: Yes I will probably do something similar to that, however, the images that we get are by default conventional SVGs, so our first step is to convert the embedded SVG groups into raster images, which we subsequently will serve.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am working on the exact same problem!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will exactly answer what you are trying to do, but you can do this:

```
<image id="something" href='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" .../>' />
```

Where you can just embed the original SVG as a string in the href when the encoding is set to `data:image/svg+xml;utf8`.

This will render the SVG in an `<image>` tag, but not in Base64 (I could not get this working, but there may be a way).

Source: https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to convert an inline SVG with tags in the DOM to an image data-url. You just need to turn it into one like this:

```
imageTag.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + window.escape(svgTag.outerHTML);
```

The imageTag version can not have external links embedded in the SVG. It also needs width and height attributes on the SVG tag otherwise it will not show in some browsers. You could also draw this image to a canvas to rasterize the image, but as the comment mentioned that would only make it uglier if scaled.

If you want to convert it to a SVG file you should add this as a first line and then add the outerHTML of the svgTag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

You can save the file with the .svg extension